# How specify the color scheme of bootstrap3 theme in pelican

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pelican

In pelican,

I set themes to bootstrap3, but I found there are different color schemes in the bootstrap theme 'paper' from https://bootswatch.com/paper/ , my question is how to specify the color scheme in pelicanconf.fy or alternatives?

pelicanconf.fy:

```
 53 BOOTSTRAP_THEME = 'paper'
 54 # BOOTSTRAP_NAVBAR_INVERSE = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the css file for each color scheme in your static css folder. and then you can edit the following lines to select the theme of your choice.

you can download all the themes from pelican-theme repositorty on github:

https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/pelican-bootstrap3/static/css

change 'paper' to whatever you like.

Comment: As a side note some of these themes need specific google font that need to be linked to or downloaded.

Comment: I have my pelican-bootstrap3 in themes directory it works well. In [https://bootswatch.com/paper/](https://bootswatch.com/paper/) , there are different color schemes, and just want to specifiy the color scheme.

Comment: the different color schemes are not available but different css classes for different objects such as buttons, etc.